# Interesting eigenvalues of adjacency graph

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, galois-theory, finite-fields

For $p$ a prime, $p>2$, my graph $G$ is defined as follows:

The vertices of $G$ are all the non self-orthogonal 1-dimensional subspaces in $\mathbb{F}_p^3$, with 2 vertices adjacent if and only if their corresponding 1-dimensional vector spaces are orthogonal.

For example, if $p = 5$:
$$u = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix} v= \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix} z = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 2
\end{bmatrix}$$
$u$ is self orthogonal because $u^\top u = 0$ in $\mathbb{F}_5$.
$v$ and $z$ are adjacent because $v^\top z = 0$.

This graph $G$, for any $p$, has order $p^2$. Vertices in $G$ have degrees of either $p-1$ or $p+1$.

Now for my question, I suspect the adjacency matrix of $G$ has the following eigenvalues (not counting multiplicities):
$$(-\sqrt{p}, \, -1, \, 0, \, \sqrt{p}, \, p)$$
The algebraic multiplicities follow an interesting pattern as well:
$$ \big( \frac{p^2-p-2}{2}, \, p, \, 1, \, \frac{p^2-p-2}{2}, \,1 \big)$$
but I have not been able to find a proof for this.

I have verified this property for primes up to and including $p=37$.
Is there perhaps a class of matrices for which the eigenvalues satisfy this relation?

Comment: You better include multiplicities in the post - they may happen to be important.

Comment: May be a route to unravelling this problem is via a closer analysis of the eigenspaces of the correponding matrix $\tilde{G}$, of size $p^2+p+1$, where you include the isotropic vectors. The eigenvalues of $\tilde{G}$ may be easier to analyze. Linear algebra tells right away that
$$\tilde{G}^2=pI+J,$$ where $J$ is the all $1$s matrix. At least with $p=3$ the eigenvalues of $\tilde{G}$ are $p+1$ (multiplicity $1$) and $\pm\sqrt{p}$ (both with equal multiplicity), the latter eigenspaces belonging to the zero sum subspace (= the zero eigenspace of $J$).

Comment: (cont'd) A fond hope is that the effect of throwing away the $p+1$ isotropic vectors as nodes of the graph would be possible to analyze, if we first fully understand the eigenspaces of $\tilde{G}$?

Comment: Anyway, I should test $\tilde{G}$ for primes other than $p=3$ next :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, ah that's smart! We can easily prove the eigenvalues of $\tilde{G}$ right? We know the eigenvalues of $J$ and adding $pI$ to that will just increase the eigenvalues with $p$. So $J$ has eigenvalues
$$\lambda_J = (p^2+p+1,0)$$
$$\lambda_{pI+J} =(p^2+2p+1,p)$$
Hence, the eigenvalues of $G$ are just the square roots of those.

Comment: Oh I think I solved it, I wanted to show that the chromatic number increases as $p$ keeps increasing by using the hoffman bound.
$$\chi(G) \geq 1 - \frac{\lambda_{max}}{\lambda_{min}}$$
will post my solution later if you are interested